# MongoDB: Aggregate query is not passing value inside the function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am facing a problem with the Mongoose aggregation query. I have the following schema which is an array of objects and contains the `endDate` value.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "endDate": "2022-02-28T19:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "endDate": "2022-02-24T19:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "endDate": "2022-02-25T19:00:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

So, during the aggregation result, I have to add a new field name `isPast`, It contains the boolean value, and perform the calculation to check if the `endDate` is passed or not. If it is already passed, then `isPast` will be `true` otherwise `false`.

I am using the `isBefore` function from the moment library which returns the boolean. But inside this function facing a problem regarding passing the `endDate` value. `$endDate` is passing as a string, not a value.

Is there a way to pass the value of endDate inside the function?

```js
const todayDate = moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD");

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "isPast": moment('$endDate', 'YYYY-MM-DD').isBefore(todayDate)
    },

  },

])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve without momentjs. Use `$toDate` to convert date-time string to date

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "isPast": {
        $gt: [
          new Date(),
          {
            $toDate: "$endDate"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rT9UJUMaucD)

---

If you just want to compare for date only:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      "currentDate": "$$NOW",
      "endDate": {
        $toDate: "$endDate"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "isPast": {
        $gt: [
          {
            "$dateFromParts": {
              "year": {
                $year: "$currentDate"
              },
              "month": {
                $month: "$currentDate"
              },
              "day": {
                "$dayOfMonth": "$currentDate"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "$dateFromParts": {
              "year": {
                $year: "$endDate"
              },
              "month": {
                $month: "$endDate"
              },
              "day": {
                "$dayOfMonth": "$endDate"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (Compare date only)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/83oSFa67Upk)